# getURL() in as2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

Hello friends my code is too big u can download here zip file http://www.filefactory.com/file/6bvfmmx3zpet/n/New_folder_4_rar

i have downloded this code from internet .. this is working fine the problem is when this code get end then the web page jump to a `URL` i tried to put

```
getURL("http://www.adobe.com","_self");
```

but its not working may be i m not aware where to put this code .... plz help me

**EDIT**

you can read my code here .. [jsfiddle.net/uM9zr](http://jsfiddle.net/uM9zr)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell from your question whether you as using AS2 or AS3 as you mention both, but getURL is not supported in AS3:

[ActionScript 3 - What happened to GetURL?](http://www.schoolofflash.com/2008/04/actionscript-3-tutorial-what-happened-to-geturl/)

Comment: thanks for your precious help .. u can read my code here .. http://jsfiddle.net/uM9zr/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "_self" with "_blank". This will open the link in a new tab, but should solve your problem of the URL not opening.

Also Mitch should read the title. AS2 was a quite obvious part of your question.